# Saving as web page in Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document in doc format. When I save that in html format in Word then the page width is changed (increased) and all text clutters up and it is very annoying to again adjust them. Is there some way to make it as a web page with a view just same as doc format (i.e with the same page width). I tried google docs but not working.

Comment: What part of Google Docs is not working? Did you try Filtered HTML in Word?

Answer (score 5):

Eww... please don't use Word to create web pages. It generates a soup of MS-specific HTML and CSS, which is horrible for browsers, and completely unmaintainable except through Word.

If you want to be designing web pages visually I recommend a tool such as [Microsoft Expression Web 3](http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Word assumes a fixed page width. That's why you can tell word how big a page should be. The web however, doesn't (or at least shouldn't) make any such assumptions. When writing HTML, either manually or using Word, you have no way of knowing how large the broser window will be when the HTML is rendered again.

If you want a fixed layout that looks exactly as it looked in Word, convert your document to PDF and offer that for download.

Answer (score 0):

In general, transforming among different file types does not maintain the fidelity of the original. You may even have problems taking the Word document to a PDF format, particularly with pagination.

Answer (score -1):

Word-HTML's paragraphs span the browser's width. Consequently, the lines of text can be very wide, which makes them visually hard to read.

There's a free program that enhances Word's HTML, to make it a usable web-page.  This includes fixing that paragraph-width problem.

https://jimyuill.com/software/www/WordWebNav/

In full disclosure, I wrote the program.  It's open source.

I wanted to post Word-docs on my personal web-site, as web-pages.
For a Word-HTML web-page to be useful, I found additional features were needed (e.g., Navigation Pane), and there are bugs in Word's HTML (e.g., multi-level lists are mis-formatted).

The program adds those additional features, and fixes Word-HTML bugs.

Comment: Why the down-vote?
My answer addresses the OP's concern about Word HTML's problem's with page-width and formatting.
I described a common cause of the reported problem, as well as a possible solution.